# garage door sensors

Tags: sensor

I know I'm overthinking this.... I've set up a sonoff inching 4-relay smart switch to "press" the garage door "buttons" for my three garage doors. So far, works OK connected to eWe server.

My quandary is how to detect if the door is open and notify me on my phone so I can act to close the door when it's been open too long. I'm familiar with magnetic reed switches, and I own a number of them. How do I make them report their status (or change of status, whatever...) and to what system?

I'm up for using Tasmoto or other tools, even a RPi if I must. I just can't seem to get it clear in my mind....

Comment: Hello and welcome. A reed switch is just a switch which happens to be activated by a different method than push button switches. Anything which can read a normal switch can read a reed switch. There are countless examples and tutorials out there which will show you how to read a switch and do things with the data. Do some background research and when you have a specific question, post it and someone will try to help.

Comment: As I said above, I'm familiar with switches, including reed switches. What device do I need to detect the switch's state change, and how can I report that state change to my devices (MQTT, alexa, whatever....) I'm looking for strategies